# Can I zoom just a part of my OrthograficCamera libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

imagine that, an imaginary minecraft, where you build cubes.

You have a panel where you have the diferents cubes(tool box),

and other big panel, the world where you build, but the world is bigger.

and all of this things are in the same screen, imagine how can i put a orthografic camera that only zoom the panel where you have the whole world, that it allows you to zoom and build cubes with details and presicion, but the tool box panel still the same position. always visible. ?

Answer (score 1):

Use two cameras.  One for the "game" and one for the "HUD".

During a render call, use one camera to render the game, then "switch" cameras and then render the HUD.  How you switch cameras depends on what API you're using to render objects (for example use [`setProjectionMatrix`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#setProjectionMatrix%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4%29) on a `SpriteBatch`).

You could also create more than one `SpriteBatch` or more than one `Stage` (as each tracks camera state internally), but they're a bit heavy-weight.

Beware that when switching contexts, you will probably have to explicitly end/flush/complete the first context before starting the second.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use one Camera to show the stuff. For example you use a Camera for the background of your game and you have a second camera for the game Hud that always has a fixed size. But the game in background can be zoomed in and out because its an different camera.
But for simple boxes on the screen you do not use a second camera. You just use one more Stage that get displayed or not where the new "ui" stuff is shown.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I cant understand, I mean, I want like to screens, the first you have the game where you can zoom in and zoom out, and its big

And the other you have a tool box, where you can use to interact with the game how can I do that

Comment: As i said you use 2 cameras for that. one that target the one thing you show, and the otherone does target the other stuf you show. You use those like a screen. You can display the content of the one camera inside the content of the other camera so you got your 2 screen. But in that case you simply jsut need 2 stages! the background stage and a stage for your window where you can interact. take a look at http://steigert.blogspot.de for getting started with stages. But there isnt the one solution for what you want!